# ElasticSearch UNASSIGNED indices fix without data loss

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

for whatever reason a bunch of indices became UNASSIGNED. I'm looking for a way of assigning them to a cluster node **without** loosing any data.

I tried using the following API call, but it results in data loss, unfortunately (due to allow_primary):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty' -d '{
        "commands" : [ {
                "allocate" : {
                    "index" : "index-name",
                    "shard" : "0",
                    "allow_primary" : true,
                    "node" : "node-name"
                }
            }
        ]
    }'
```

I also keep getting the following entries in elasticsearch.log:

```
[2015-03-16 11:51:12,181][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [cluster node] All shards failed for phase: [query_fetch]
[2015-03-16 11:51:12,450][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [cluster node] All shards failed for phase: [query_fetch]
[2015-03-16 11:51:19,349][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [cluster node] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
[2015-03-16 11:51:20,057][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [cluster node] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
```

Any help would be appreciated.